# error: expected unqualified-id before '+' token

Tags: c++, gcc, codeblocks, iostream, header-files

I am running CodeBlocks from the mingw setup. When I try to run any code I receive this error, while the compiler cites `#include <iostream>` as the source of the error.

Here is the code I was trying to run:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    for(int x = 0; x<=1000; x++)
        cout<< x;

    return 0;
}
```

That's all of it. No more or less. 
I can't make sense of it, and it has been doing this even after reinstalling.

Build log:

```
--- Build: Debug in Test Project (compiler: GNU GCC Compiler)---

mingw32-g++.exe -Wall -fexceptions  -g     -c "C:\Users\Justin\Desktop\CPP Project\Test Project\main.cpp" -o obj\Debug\main.o
C:\Users\Justin\Desktop\CPP Project\Test Project\main.cpp:1:1: error: expected unqualified-id before '+' token
Process terminated with status 1 (0 minutes, 0 seconds)
1 errors, 0 warnings (0 minutes, 0 seconds)
```

Okay, so I've editted the code to do literally nothing and still get the exact same error.

This is the new code:

```
int main()
{
    return 0;
}
```

The build log and error remain as is above.

Comment: Are you compiling with c++ (or at leas have .cpp filename)?

Comment: This is the filename it says it is executing for the C++ Compiler: mingw32-g++.exe

Comment: The file being compiled is just main.cpp

Comment: Can you please copy-paste the complete build log (from the console window/tab) into your question

Comment: @nKandel Thanks for the edit. I'm extremely new to this.

Comment: code work fine in my case with codeblocks 10:04

Comment: I'm currently using Codeblocks 12.11

Comment: `main.cpp:1:1` means that the error is on the very first character of your file (line 1 column 1), as if it were [this](http://ideone.com/sn76CU). That might be an encoding problem implying invisible [BOM characters](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) at the start of the file. I suggest you do a hexdump of main.cpp (or open it in a hex editor) and check the first characters.